# Turning wsdl result into a multiple line list

Tags: java, string, netbeans-platform

In my programming class we have been assigned a task to get results from a wsdl and seperate the results into a list.  For example,

children & family;children;family;friends

The task is to seperate the line at every ";" and input the information on the next line, so it transforms from a line into a list, such as..

children & family
children
family
friends

How do I got about doing this?  I've been stuck for quite awhile.

This is all in Java by the way

Comment: What is your wsdl content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say `String wsdlString` would be what you get as input and the result of your method should be a `ArrayList<String>`:

```
public ArrayList<String> seperateIntoList(String wsdlString){
      String[] resultArray =  wsdlString.split(";");
      ArrayList<String> resultList = new ArrayList<String>(resultArray.size());

      for(String listItem: resultArray) {
          resultList.add(listItem);
      }

      return resultList;
}
```

I wasn't quite sure, but if you only want a String with linebreaks instead of a `List` you can just use `wsdlString.replace(";","\n");`